# Spring Boot 3 WebFlux with router function can't deserialize Record from json

Tags: java, jackson, spring-webflux, record

I'm sending a json to my WebFlux application and I'm receiving a 415 Unsupported Media Type exception.

Here is my routerFunction:

```
@Bean
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> groupRoute(GroupController groupController) {
    return route()
      .POST("/group", accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), groupController::addGroup);
}
```

Here is my controller method:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> addGroup(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
    return serverRequest.bodyToMono(CreateGroupRequest.class)
            .flatMap(srvApiDb::createGroup)
            .flatMap(response -> ServerResponse.ok().build());
}
```

And here is my record:

```
public record CreateGroupRequest(@JsonUnwrapped Group group) {
}
```

When I change my record for a "normal" class, everything works like it should...
Do anyone knows how to make it work with a Record class?